# glassfish + jk + large file/strange response

Tags: apache2, glassfish-3, mod-jk

I use a Glassfish-ApplicationServer for a Webapplication. The Glassfish is connected with mod_jk to a Apache2-Server.
Now there is a really strange behavior: Some Parts of the received Files (html, css, js, ...) are missing and there are strange numbers in the Files... If I use the direct access to the Glassfish eth works.

I use Glassfish 3.1.2, mod_jk 1.2.33 and Apache2. The Webapplication uses jsf/Primefaces 3.2.

In the mod_jk log there are strange error Messages. The Messages apear only on the first access to the Webpage.

```
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3763:2928831344] [error]ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1280): wrong message format 0x2020 from 127.0.0.1:9009
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3763:2928831344] [error] ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2145): (ajp13_worker) Tomcat is down or network problems. Part of the response has already been sent to the client
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3763:2928831344] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2614): (ajp13_worker) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of protocol error (attempt=2)
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3763:2928831344] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2634): (ajp13_worker) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3763:2928831344] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2788): Service error=-11 for worker=ajp13_worker
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] ajp13_worker ores.pragma.biz 0.191397
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3764:2903653232] [error] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1280): wrong message format 0x6973 from 127.0.0.1:9009
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3764:2903653232] [error] ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2145): (ajp13_worker) Tomcat is down or network problems. Part of the response has already been sent to the client
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3764:2903653232] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2614): (ajp13_worker) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of protocol error (attempt=2)
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3764:2903653232] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2634): (ajp13_worker) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Mon Mar 19 13:33:42 2012] [3764:2903653232] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2788): Service error=-11 for worker=ajp13_worker
```

Hope, that anybody can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing GF 3.1.1 and see if that fixes the problem.  I read about this bug last week, which might be your problem: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18446  Looks like there is a patch available on that bug.

Comment: Worked :). thx. A update with the update-tool will be a good idea.

Comment: The work around in the bug works also if you really want to use 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, but if by any chance you're using `apache` and `mod_jk` only as a proxy to GF (as we did for years) - install `nginx`, and forget about `apache`. It's like day and night.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

Comment: Nice Programm. Not for this Problem, because the Server is integrated in some other things, but for the (Master)Webserver, which accesses VM's :) thx